# Ubuntu 16.04 hanging VPS server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, administrator, linux-kernel

I have a weird issue with a VPS server I am using for a personal project.
The server started hanging at 10:40 yesterday
The last line from /var/log/syslog before hanging was:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Today it happened again the same output.

1. What can be causing this issue? Might it be from my VPS provider or some kernel issue?
2. How can I proceed to identify the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What type of virtualization are you using? Try to install atop and analyze processlist and resource usage before server hanging.

Check your **/etc/rsyslog.conf** and **/etc/rsyslog.d** directory and find programs which writes logs to syslog.